# Installed pytesser, but can't import it

Tags: python, tesseract, python-module, python-tesseract, pytesser

I am trying to install PyTesser to use as an OCR in my script.
The README in its .zip source says:

> PyTesser has no installation functionality in this release.  Extract pytesser.zip
>   into directory with other scripts.

I then extracted `pytesser_v0.0.1.zip` to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pytesser`.

However, when I try to import it in VS2013 (using `from pytesser import *`), I get a `No module named pytesser` error.

What am I doing wrong? I am using Python 2.7, by the way. I know that PIL isn't supported in Python 3+.

Thanks!

UPDATE: I found that I may be able to add modules by editing the PYTHONPATH variable, but this seems both hacky and unreliable.

UPDATE 2: Yay, I got the Tumbleweed badge!

UPDATE 3: Here are the files in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pytesser:

```
 Directory of C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pytesser

16 Aug 2015  03:55 PM    <DIR>          .
16 Aug 2015  03:55 PM    <DIR>          ..
16 Aug 2015  03:55 PM               273 AUTHORS
16 Aug 2015  03:55 PM                48 ChangeLog
16 Aug 2015  03:55 PM               424 errors.py
16 Aug 2015  03:55 PM             1,410 fnord.tif
16 Aug 2015  03:55 PM            20,607 fonts_test.png
16 Aug 2015  03:55 PM               558 LICENSE
16 Aug 2015  03:55 PM               337 NOTICE
16 Aug 2015  03:55 PM            38,668 phototest.tif
16 Aug 2015  03:55 PM             2,560 pytesser.py
16 Aug 2015  03:55 PM             2,652 README
16 Aug 2015  03:55 PM    <DIR>          tessdata
16 Aug 2015  03:55 PM           827,392 tesseract.exe
16 Aug 2015  03:55 PM               669 util.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to edit PYTHONPATH, `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\` is already in your PYTHONPATH.  Can you list the tree that you extracted pytesser into? Under `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pytesser` should be a file called `__init__.py`, my guess is that you extracted the files under an additional directory in that tree.  You could also try opening a python prompt and typing

`import sys
print sys.path`

To verify that `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\` is in fact in your path.

Comment: @Princee that probably means when you extracted it a new directory was created inside C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pytesser\.  You may need to move everything from C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pytesser\<extraced name> to C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pytesser\

Comment: The only folder in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pytesser\` is `tessdata`, and I think it's supposed to be there.

Comment: OK, so you extracted correctly but there should be a bunch of other stuff in there.  @Princee I got the .zip from here and saw the .py files in it that I would expect, maybe try re-downloading?  https://code.google.com/p/pytesser/downloads/detail?name=pytesser_v0.0.1.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: I have re-downloaded and re-extracted; there isn't any difference in the contents of `pytesser/`. What is the name of the file I'm missing? `__init__.py`?

Comment: @Princee that and pytesser.py and errors.py, etc.  Did you download from the link I posted in last comment?!